# Is there a way to pull outliers into a separate df?

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers

Hi I have a data frame with 150 Columns and 200 rows and I want to go through each column and pull any data points that are more than 3 sd from the mean of each column.

|  | G-198804 | G-198712 | G-228253 | G-198899 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X1027** | 15.100481 | 15.949672 | 13.783062 | 17.106806 |
| **X1104** | 14.905931 | 15.766908 | 13.885380 | 17.134476 |
| **X5010** | 15.268376 | 16.457303 | 13.447923 | 17.345957 |
| **X5023** | 15.513746 | 16.457871 | 13.848918 | 17.634144 |
| **X5425** | 15.093679 | 16.085498 | 13.253646 | 17.066823 |
| **X7CUH** | 15.471564 | 16.417165 | 13.764880 | 17.365255 |
| **X8VHB** | 15.222530 | 16.440389 | 13.146401 | 17.158754 |
| **VWU2** | 14.999256 | 16.121702 | 13.261694 | 17.193140 |
| **CUKX** | 14.795677 | 16.076999 | 13.325234 | 17.145046 |

I used this to replace the outliers with *NA*, but I realized I needed the outliers in a separate df. Is there any way to modify this to just pull the row and column name of the cells that are outliers?

```
newtpose = tpose_genexp %>% 
mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("G")), 
          .funs= ~ifelse(abs(.)>mean(.)+3*sd(.), NA, .))
```

My new data frame would hopefully look like

| Sample | Gene |
| --- | --- |
| X1027 | G-198712 |
| X7CUH | G-228253 |

Comment: Replacing outliers with NA with no consideration of the cause is a statistical distortion of the data.

Comment: What would this separate df look like? Is it just NA's except for the values >3SD from mean? You could make that using the code above but ending `., NA))`

Comment: @IRTFM I am trying to subset them to see which samples are producing the outliers. I thought I could compare the two dfs (the one with all the values and the one with NA's) and manually write out those samples and corresponding gene so I could have that stored for further information. Not trying to distort the data at all

Comment: @JonSpring The new data frame would have two columns hopefully one with the genename and one with the sample ID. ie. G-198804, X5425

Comment: It would be much simpler to help you if you could post a reproducible snippet of your data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a new data frame, say `df_out`, in which all those values that are **not** outliers are set to NA:

```
df_out <- df %>% 
       mutate(across(starts_with("G"), 
        ~ifelse(abs(.) > mean(.) + 3*sd(.), ., NA)))
```

If you want the outliers in a two-column dataframe, you can add `pivot_longer`:

```
df %>% 
       mutate(across(starts_with("G"),
        ~ifelse(abs(.) > mean(.) + 3*sd(.), NA, .))) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  na.omit
```